# Install RVM in a specific location

Tags: ruby, rvm

Installing RVM with command below gets installed to `${HOME}/.rvm`. Instead, I'm looking for a way to specify the location where `.rvm` directory gets created so that I can control where RVM is installed.

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Is there a way to specify this while installing RVM?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by creating a symlink from ~/.rvm to $TARGET_DIR and *before* installing rvm. In this example I am using a directory called 'myrvm':

```
    ln -sf myrvm/ ~/.rvm
```

Then when I check the contents of 'myrvm', I see rvm is installed there. RVM still works seemlessly